# Polymorphic variable used in different contexts haskell

Tags: haskell, polymorphism

I have a following piece of Haskell code:

```
foo :: Num a => (a -> a) -> Either Integer Double -> Either Integer Double
foo f x = case x of
  Left i -> Left $ f i
  Right d -> Right $ f d
```

It doesn't compile with error "Couldn't match type Integer with Double". I understand that type of `f` is computed as `Integer -> Integer` and `Double -> Double` in `Left` and `Right` expressions respectively, creating a collision.

How can I change this function, so that correct version of `f` would be used each time?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need `RankNTypes`.

```
{-# LANGUAGE RankNTypes #-}

foo :: (forall a. Num a => a -> a) -> Either Integer Double -> Either Integer Double
foo f x = case x of
    Left i -> Left $ f i
    Right d -> Right $ f d
```